# Assigning a selected option from a dropdown to a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to assign the chosen option from the dropdown to become the `selectedSubject` variable but am having problems with it, I had code which half worked...

```
selectedSubject = $('select#subject-options').val();
```

But when a different option is selected it doesn't change?? 
And need it change for the game I am creating

HTML:

```
<p>Subjects</p>
<select id="subject-options" name="subject-options">
  <option selected disabled >Please Choose</option>
  <option id="BBT" value="$BBT">Big Bang Theory</option>
  <option value="$LOTR">Lord Of The Rings</option>
  <option value="$EPL">EPL Football Teams</option>
  <option value="$ASIA">Asian Countries</option>`
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
const $BBT = ['sheldon','leanord','spock','cheescake``factory','howard','raj','star` `trek','penny','amy','bernadette','physics','laundry','halo` `night','dumplings', 'brisket','nasa','string theory','dark matter',` `'comiccon'];

let selectedSubject = $BBT;
selectedSubject = selectedSubject[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectedSubject.length)];
```

I have been through 7 different questions similar and couldn't find anything that helped me, so if anyone could help me directly or direct me to another question that has been answered that will help me in my troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add an event handler to `#subject-options` to update the `selectedSubject` variable each time you change your selection.

```
$('#subject-options').on('change', function() {
    selectedSubject = $('#subject-options option:checked').val();
});
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/nodeleritu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery selector you grab the `select` object itself. You need the `option` object and especially the one that is `selected`.

```
selectedSubject = $('select#subject-options option:selected').val();
```